# Limits of functions in metric spaces and limits of real functions

Tags: general-topology

I defined limits of functions in general topological spaces as following: Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_{1})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_{2})$ topological spaces. Let $\mathcal{U}_{x}$ denote the neighbourhood system of a point $x$. Let $A\subseteq X$ and let $f:A\rightarrow Y$ be a map. We write $f(x)\rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow x_{0}$, if and only if
\begin{align*}
(\forall V \in\mathcal{U}_{a})
(\exists U \in\mathcal{U}_{x_{0}}): 
f[(U\setminus\{x_{0}\})\cap A]\subseteq V.
\end{align*}

Now I want to derive similar formulations for metric spaces and later on for real numbers. For real numbers I think the statement would be $f(x)\rightarrow a$ as $x\rightarrow x_{0}$ if and only if
\begin{align*}
(\forall \epsilon >0)(\exists \delta >0)(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):[0<|x-x_{0}|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-a|<\epsilon].
\end{align*}
However, so far I couldn't come up with a formulation for metric spaces, let alone an idea how to prove them from the definition given above. Furthermore I couldn't find any book or webpage which covers this. Would be great if anyone could help me with this or point me to a useful text about this topic.

Comment: I think [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_on_metric_spaces)'s definition is precisely yours. It just replaces absolute value by the respective metrics on both sets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Claim:** Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,\rho)$ be two metric spaces. If $A \subseteq X$, $x_0 \in X$, $y_0 \in Y$, and $f : A \to Y$, then $f(x) \to y_0$ as $x \to x_0$ if and only if
> $$
> (\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in A)(0 < d(x,x_0) < \delta \implies \rho(f(x),y_0) < \varepsilon).
> $$

*Proof*: I will only prove the *only if* direction (meaning $\!\implies\!$), so suppose that $f(x) \to y_0$ as $x \to x_0$, and take $\varepsilon>0$. Then the ball $B(y_0,\varepsilon) = \{y \in Y : \rho(y,y_0) < \varepsilon\}$ is an element of $\mathcal U_{y_0}$, and so we know that there exists $U \in \mathcal U_{x_0}$ such that
$$f((U \setminus \{x_0\}) \cap A) \subseteq B(y_0,\varepsilon).$$
Also, we know that there is a $\delta>0$ such that $U$ contains $B(x_0,\delta) = \{x \in X : d(x,x_0)<\delta\}$, so for every $x \in A$ with $0 < d(x,x_0) < \delta$ we have $x \in (U \setminus \{x_0\}) \cap A$, and then $f(x) \in B(y_0,\varepsilon)$.

---

In particular,  if $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, $x_0,y_0 \in \mathbb R$, and $f : A \to \mathbb R$, then $f(x) \to y_0$ as $x \to x_0$ if and only if
$$
(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0)(\forall x \in A)(0 < |x-x_0| < \delta \implies |f(x)-y_0| < \varepsilon).
$$

Comment: When thinking about this again, I stumbled on a potential issue. Since $\epsilon >0$ we have $y_{0}\not\in B_{\epsilon}(y_{0})$, so $B_{\epsilon}(y_{0})$ can't be a neighbourhood of $y_{0}$, i.e. $B_{\epsilon}(y_{0})\not\in \mathcal{U}_{y_{0}}$... or did I miss something here?

Comment: @PAT Observe that $y \in B(y_0,\varepsilon) \iff \rho(y,y_0) < \varepsilon$. Since $\rho(y_0,y_0)=0<\varepsilon$, we have $y_0 \in B(y_0,\varepsilon)$.

Comment: Ah right, my bad.. guess was overthinking things. thanks